# Limit text input size based on db schema in rails simpleform

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, simple-form, simple-form-for

I have HTML input fields created with simple_form.

```
  <%= simple_form_for @user do |f|%>
     <%= f.input :name %>
  <% end %>
```

If the user inputs data bigger than the database field limit, I get an error:

> Data too long for column 'name' at row

How can I automatically limit the input maxlength based on the database field size? For exemple, a `varchar(100)` would be limit by 100.

Comment: You have your answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15063500/how-simpleform-maxlength-extension-works

Comment: @cristian I put `b.use :maxlength` in `simple_form.rb` but still it does not work